# Loading list of objects from application yml Java Spring Boot

Tags: java

I've got this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "House")
public class ProjectConfig{

    private List<HouseTemplate> templates;

    // getters and setters
}
```

HouseTemplate class:

```
public class HouseTemplate{

    private String id;
    private String description;

    // getters and setters
}
```

this is my application-test.yml

```
House:
  templates:
    -
      id: "COLONIAL"
      description: "Colonial house template"
    -
      id: "COTTAGE"
      description: "Cottage house template"
    -
      id: "Apartment"
      description: "Apartment house template"


exampleString: hello
```

In my test class I have the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = ProjectConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml")
public class YamlApplicationContextLoadingSpec {

    @Value("${exampleString}")
    String example;

    @Autowired
    ProjectConfig projectConfig;


    @Test
    public void exampleShouldContainHello(){
        assertThat(example).isEqualToIgnoringCase("hello");
    }
   
    @Test
    public void appContextContainsHouseTemplates(){
        List<HouseTemplate> houseTemplates = projectConfig.getTemplates();
        assertThat(houseTemplates).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

The first test about the exampleString passes, while the second doesn't. Why is it not able to map the yml to the list of HouseTemplate?

**EDIT**

```
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>

<artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
<version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>

<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
```

I know they are really old and I would love to upgrade but I can't so... that's what I got to work with.

Answer (score 0):

After using `@ConfigurationProperties` to read from yml, you can register it as a bean, and then you can get it by `ApplicationContext`.

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "House")
public class TestConfig {

    private List<HouseTemplate> templates;

    @Bean
    public List<HouseTemplate> templates() {
        return templates;
    }

    // getter and setter
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @GetMapping("get")
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<HouseTemplate> get() {
        return (List<HouseTemplate>) applicationContext.getBean("templates");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to register as a bean, you can also declare variable as static.

Here is an example.

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "House")
public class TestConfig {

    private static List<HouseTemplate> templates;

    public static List<HouseTemplate> get() {
        return templates;
    }

    public List<HouseTemplate> getTemplates() {
        return templates;
    }

    public void setTemplates(List<HouseTemplate> templates) {
        TestConfig.templates = templates;
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("get")
    public List<HouseTemplate> get() {
        return TestConfig.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer has nothing to do with my question. My question is about not being able to inject a list of object from a yml file.

Comment: I think  I am not misunderstood, you can't call `getTemplates()` to get the list, just like the example that I posted, you should define it as a bean or declare templates as `static`, otherwise it will return a null.

Comment: I've tried both the `static` and the `bean`... still null

Answer (score 0):

The mapping does not happen because Spring Boot is not configured for your test-class. Spring Boot functions do the mapping, so these need to be enabled for your test-class.

While testing I also found that `TestPropertySource` does not play well with Spring Boot, `ActiveProfiles` can be used as a replacement.

There are two ways to get Spring Boot to do the mapping. The first (shown below) is useful for most Spring Boot tests, the latter is geared toward speed.

I am using Spring Boot version 2.7.18 with dependencies:
`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent` (parent)
`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter`
`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test` (scope `test`)
`org.projectlombok:lombok` (scope `provided`)

The general Spring Boot test setup:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = ConfigLoadBootTest.Config.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test") // loads application-test.yml
@Slf4j
public class ConfigLoadBootTest {

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(ProjectConfig.class)
    static class Config {}
    
    @Value("${exampleString}")
    String example;

    @Autowired
    ProjectConfig houseConfig;

    @Test
    void haveProps() {

        log.info("Example: {}", example);
        Assertions.assertThat(example).isEqualTo("hello");
        log.info("Houses: {}", houseConfig.getHouses());
        Assertions.assertThat(houseConfig.getHouses()).hasSize(3);
    }
}
```

The test more geared toward speed:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class, // was ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer
    classes = ConfigLoadContextTest.Config.class
)
@ActiveProfiles("test") // loads application-test.yml
@Slf4j
public class ConfigLoadContextTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(ProjectConfig.class)
    static class Config {}
    
    @Value("${exampleString}")
    String example;

    @Autowired
    ProjectConfig houseConfig;

    @Test
    void haveProps() {

        log.info("Example: {}", example);
        Assertions.assertThat(example).isEqualTo("hello");
        log.info("Houses: {}", houseConfig.getHouses());
        Assertions.assertThat(houseConfig.getHouses()).hasSize(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I was using those versions... sorry I edited my question with my actual dependency versions

Answer (score 0):

#### Most problem

`prefix = "House"` ...:

```bash
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Configuration property name 'House' is not valid:

    Invalid characters: 'H'
    Bean: demoConfigApplication.DemoController
    Reason: Canonical names should be kebab-case ('-' separated), lowercase alpha-numeric characters and must start with a letter       

Action:

Modify 'House' so that it conforms to the canonical names requirements.
```

#### Solution

Kebab-case "house" (in configuration properties source file, yaml file can remain as is...)

1. ProjectConfig:

   ```java
   // no @Configuration(!?)
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "house") //! kebab-case
   public class ProjectConfig {

      private List<HouseTemplate> templates;

      // ...

   }
   ```
2. SpringBootApp:

   ```java
   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableConfigurationProperties(ProjectConfig.class) // !
   ```
3. (yaml file as in OP, but name it (default) `application.yaml`)
4. Controller:

   ```java
   @Controller
   class DemoController {
      @Autowired // !
      ProjectConfig pc;

      @GetMapping("hello")
      public ResponseEntity<List<HouseTemplate>> hello() {
        if (pc == null || pc.getTemplates() == null) {
          return (ResponseEntity<List<HouseTemplate>>) ResponseEntity.notFound();
        } else {
          return ResponseEntity.ok(pc.getTemplates());
        }
      }
    }
   ```

   (try out at http://localhost:8080/hello)
5. Test:

   (Works from `application.yaml`)

   ```java
   @SpringBootTest
   class DemoConfigApplicationTests {


       @Value("${exampleString}")
       String example;

       @Autowired
       ProjectConfig projectConfig;

       @Test
       void exampleShouldContainHello() {
            assertThat(example).isEqualToIgnoringCase("hello");
       }

       @Test
       void appContextContainsHouseTemplates() {
            List<HouseTemplate> houseTemplates = projectConfig.getTemplates();
            assertThat(houseTemplates).isNotNull();
       }
   }
   ```
6. To make it work from `application-test.yaml`, just annotate: `@ActiveProfiles("test")` on our test class.

#### Hint

To override application.yaml for tests, simplest approach is to provide it (additionally) in `src/test/resources`.

#### Reference

(mainly)  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties

Comment: thank you for you answer, unfortunately when I try what you suggest I simply get a `NullPointerException` on `projectConfig.getTemplates();` I don't know which versions of JUnit, Spring and SpringBoot you're using but I need to add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@EnableConfigurationProperties(ProjectConfig.class)` on my test class (the `@SpringBootTest` doesn't do anything for me) to be able to correctly instantiate the Bean and inject it.

Comment: I've edited my question with dependency versions

Comment: Also I've tried going from `House` to `house` but nothing

Comment: oh, sorry, i "fixed" on the "current" (spring boot) version... spring-boot:1 is an old darling... we need to research/try out!